# How to store data from nested foreach calls into nested html data

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

#### Please see update section:

I have code similar to this example:

```
@code {

    QuestionsModel questions = ApiService.GetQuestions("http://questions.example"); 
    foreach(var q in questions){
    
        AnswersModel answers = ApiService.GetAnswers(q.url);
        foreach(var a in answers){
        
            UsersModel users = ApiService.GetUsers(a.url);      
        }
    }
}
```

This works without issues because I can loop through `questions`, `answers`, and `users` and display the result.

The problem is I want to nest the responses instead of displaying them on each row.

I want the output to look like this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach(var q in questions) {
    
        // question 1
            // related answers
                // related users
                
        // question 2
            // related answers
                // related users
    }
<ul>
```

This is a bit advanced C# code for me and I can't seem to figure out how the nesting works.

---

#### UPDATE

Ok here is the real and full code.

```
TestSuiteModel TestSuites;
TestCasesModel TestCases;
TestCaseModel TestCase;

public async Task GetTestSuites()
{
    

    string url = "https://dev.azure.com/****/****/_apis/test/Plans/12/suites?api-version=5.0";
    TestSuites = await TestSuiteService.GetTestSuites(url);

    if(TestSuites != null)
    {
        foreach (var ts in TestSuites.value)
        {
            TestCases = await TestCasesService.GetTestCases(ts.testCasesUrl);
            if (TestCases?.value != null)
            {
                foreach (var tcs in TestCases.value)
                {
                    TestCase = await TestCaseService.GetTestCase(tcs.testCase.url);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

 
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await this.GetTestSuites();
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

There is no issue with the code above. I can render `TestSuites`, `TestCases` and `TestCase` individually.  The problem is I need to store all data as a heirarchy. As in, first list `TestSuites` and then any `TestCases` related to it, and then finally the `TestCase` in the same style as:

```
show TestSuites
    show TestCases
       show TestCase
```

Here is the model for each of the above:

```
namespace ABC.Models.TestSuiteModel
{
    public class DefaultConfiguration
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Plan
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestSuiteModel
    {
        public List<Value> value { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Project project { get; set; }
        public Plan plan { get; set; }
        public int revision { get; set; }
        public int testCaseCount { get; set; }
        public string suiteType { get; set; }
        public string testCasesUrl { get; set; }
        public bool inheritDefaultConfigurations { get; set; }
        public List<DefaultConfiguration> defaultConfigurations { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public Parent parent { get; set; }
        public int? requirementId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? lastPopulatedDate { get; set; }
        public string queryString { get; set; }
    }


}
```

--

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ABC.Models.TestCasesModel
{


    public class Avatar
        {
            public string href { get; set; }
        }

        public class Configuration
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
        }

        public class Links
        {
            public Avatar avatar { get; set; }
        }

        public class PointAssignment
        {
            public Configuration configuration { get; set; }
            public Tester tester { get; set; }
        }

        public class TestCasesModel
        {
            public List<Value> value { get; set; }
            public int count { get; set; }
        }

        public class TestCase
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public string webUrl { get; set; }
        }

        public class Tester
        {
            public string displayName { get; set; }
            public string url { get; set; }
            public Links _links { get; set; }
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string uniqueName { get; set; }
            public string imageUrl { get; set; }
            public string descriptor { get; set; }
        }

        public class Value
        {
            public TestCase testCase { get; set; }
            public List<PointAssignment> pointAssignments { get; set; }
        }




}
```

.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ABC.Models.TestCaseModel
{
    public class Avatar
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fields
    {
        [JsonProperty("System.AreaPath")]
        public string SystemAreaPath { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.TeamProject")]
        public string SystemTeamProject { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.IterationPath")]
        public string SystemIterationPath { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.WorkItemType")]
        public string SystemWorkItemType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.State")]
        public string SystemState { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.Reason")]
        public string SystemReason { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.AssignedTo")]
        public SystemAssignedTo SystemAssignedTo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.CreatedDate")]
        public DateTime SystemCreatedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.CreatedBy")]
        public SystemCreatedBy SystemCreatedBy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.ChangedDate")]
        public DateTime SystemChangedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.ChangedBy")]
        public SystemChangedBy SystemChangedBy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.CommentCount")]
        public int SystemCommentCount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.Title")]
        public string SystemTitle { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate")]
        public DateTime MicrosoftVSTSCommonStateChangeDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate")]
        public DateTime MicrosoftVSTSCommonActivatedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy")]
        public MicrosoftVSTSCommonActivatedBy MicrosoftVSTSCommonActivatedBy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority")]
        public int MicrosoftVSTSCommonPriority { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus")]
        public string MicrosoftVSTSTCMAutomationStatus { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Html
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links
    {
        public Avatar avatar { get; set; }
        public Self self { get; set; }
        public WorkItemUpdates workItemUpdates { get; set; }
        public WorkItemRevisions workItemRevisions { get; set; }
        public WorkItemComments workItemComments { get; set; }
        public Html html { get; set; }
        public WorkItemType workItemType { get; set; }
        public Fields fields { get; set; }
    }

    public class MicrosoftVSTSCommonActivatedBy
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string uniqueName { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public string descriptor { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestCaseModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int rev { get; set; }
        public Fields fields { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Self
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class SystemAssignedTo
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string uniqueName { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public string descriptor { get; set; }
    }

    public class SystemChangedBy
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string uniqueName { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public string descriptor { get; set; }
    }

    public class SystemCreatedBy
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string uniqueName { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public string descriptor { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkItemComments
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkItemRevisions
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkItemType
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkItemUpdates
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }



}
```

Comment: Do you mean a 2D multidimensional array, i.e. `T[,]`, or a jagged array, i.e. `T[][]`? Is each question guaranteed to have the same number of answers? Or do you actually want a *table* of questions/answers?

Comment: @JonasH Anything that produces the desired result is good for me. Yes, I want a table but nested.

Comment: I would suggest that you update the question & title. *Array* have a very specific meaning in C#. If you are asking how to present data to the user in a table, then your title should reflect that.

Comment: @JonasH thanks for the correction, i have updated the title. I thought an array was the only way to store the data like `[questions => [ answer 1 => [user1, user2]]` but maybe there are other way to do this better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a starting point.  Is this what you want?

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

@foreach (var question in this.Questions)
{
    <div class="bg-light m-2 p-1">
        <h2>@question.Name</h2>
        @foreach (var answer in question.Answers)
        {
            <div class="m-2 p-1 ps-3">
                <h3>@answer.Text</h3>
                @foreach (var user in answer.Users)
                {
                    <div class="m-2 p-1 ps-5">
                        @user.Name
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}

@code {

    public record User(string Name);
    public record Answer(string Text, IEnumerable<User> Users);
    public record Question(string Name, IEnumerable<Answer> Answers);

    // Dummy data set which you build out using your queries
    public IEnumerable<Question> Questions =>
        new List<Question> {
            new Question(
                "The Capital of France?",
                new List<Answer> {
                    new Answer("Lyon", new List<User> { new("Jon"), new("Fred")} ),
                    new Answer("Paris", new List<User> { new("Alli"), new("Joan")} ),
            }),
            new Question(
                "The Capital of Spain?",
                new List<Answer> {
                    new Answer("Madrid", new List<User> { new("Shaun"), new("Fred")} ),
                    new Answer("Barcelona", new List<User> { new("Gustav"), new("Joe")} ),
            })
        };
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again @MrC aka Shaun Curtis Well, the end result is exactly what I expected but the your code is very different from mine. If I use your code I need to re-write everything and probably get lost. I also like the approach I gave in my example, using three models `Questions`, `Answers`, and `Users`

Comment: @elektra - [Polite] The problem in answering questions where you don't provide any detail on your models is we have to guess what they look like - and without any context is can be a wild guess!!  That's why I keep them as simple as possible.   For example `AnswersModel` should be a simple class, but your API call suggests it's a list??

Comment: understood np, but the Model in this case does not add any value. I don't even have a model called ContinentModel, CountryModel ... I just want to see the logic then I can repeat it in my code.

Posting the real models can take hundereds of lines. My question is generally how to use an array (or something similar) as a property bag to store these incoming values from the API

Comment: Just for clarification put an abbreviated version of `QuestionsModel` in your question to demonstrate it's basic structure.

Comment: I updated the question with all the real code and real module. I added a 100 bounty as well. Good luck and thanks :)

Comment: @elektra This answer is correct for your initial question, your update is quite mutating the original question into a new one: you should probably ask a new question. You added quite a lot of code and not much explanations. I would have some comments but I do believe a new question would be required.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine ok, here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75580755/how-to-store-data-from-nested-foreach-calls-to-display-it-into-nested-html-data

Comment: @MrC aka Shaun Curtis if you want to answer this question, please answer the new one instead  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75580755/how-to-store-data-from-nested-foreach-calls-to-display-it-into-nested-html-data I will give you the bounty (SO says I must wait 7 hours to give you) since I have assigned it to this question