# How to store data from nested foreach calls to display it into nested html data

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have the following code that works without issue:

```
    TestSuiteModel TestSuites;
    TestCasesModel TestCases;
    TestCaseModel TestCase;
    
    public async Task GetTestSuites()
    {
        

    string url = "https://dev.azure.com/****/****/_apis/test/Plans/12/suites?api-version=5.0";
    TestSuites = await TestSuiteService.GetTestSuites(url);

    if(TestSuites != null)
    {
        foreach (var ts in TestSuites.value)
        {
            TestCases = await TestCasesService.GetTestCases(ts.testCasesUrl);
            if (TestCases?.value != null)
            {
                foreach (var tcs in TestCases.value)
                {
                    TestCase = await TestCaseService.GetTestCase(tcs.testCase.url);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await this.GetTestSuites();
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
```

Now, I would like to create some kind of array, dictionary or list to store the data inside each loop and display it this way:

```
foreach(var ts in TestSuites)
    show TestSuites
    foreach(var tcs in TestCases)
      show TestCases
         foreach(var tc in TestCase)
            show TestCase
```

The problem is i have tried but could not store and display the data this way.

Here are the three models:

##### TestSuiteModel

```
namespace ABC.Models.TestSuiteModel
{
    public class DefaultConfiguration
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Parent
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Plan
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Project
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestSuiteModel
    {
        public List<Value> value { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Project project { get; set; }
        public Plan plan { get; set; }
        public int revision { get; set; }
        public int testCaseCount { get; set; }
        public string suiteType { get; set; }
        public string testCasesUrl { get; set; }
        public bool inheritDefaultConfigurations { get; set; }
        public List<DefaultConfiguration> defaultConfigurations { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; }
        public DateTime lastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
        public Parent parent { get; set; }
        public int? requirementId { get; set; }
        public DateTime? lastPopulatedDate { get; set; }
        public string queryString { get; set; }
    }
      }
```

##### TestCasesModel

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ABC.Models.TestCasesModel
{


public class Avatar
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Configuration
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links
    {
        public Avatar avatar { get; set; }
    }

    public class PointAssignment
    {
        public Configuration configuration { get; set; }
        public Tester tester { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestCasesModel
    {
        public List<Value> value { get; set; }
        public int count { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestCase
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public string webUrl { get; set; }
    }

    public class Tester
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string uniqueName { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public string descriptor { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        public TestCase testCase { get; set; }
        public List<PointAssignment> pointAssignments { get; set; }
    }

        }
```

##### TestCaseModel

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ABC.Models.TestCaseModel
{
    public class Avatar
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Fields
    {
        [JsonProperty("System.AreaPath")]
        public string SystemAreaPath { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.TeamProject")]
        public string SystemTeamProject { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.IterationPath")]
        public string SystemIterationPath { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.WorkItemType")]
        public string SystemWorkItemType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.State")]
        public string SystemState { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.Reason")]
        public string SystemReason { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.AssignedTo")]
        public SystemAssignedTo SystemAssignedTo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.CreatedDate")]
        public DateTime SystemCreatedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.CreatedBy")]
        public SystemCreatedBy SystemCreatedBy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.ChangedDate")]
        public DateTime SystemChangedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.ChangedBy")]
        public SystemChangedBy SystemChangedBy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.CommentCount")]
        public int SystemCommentCount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("System.Title")]
        public string SystemTitle { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StateChangeDate")]
        public DateTime MicrosoftVSTSCommonStateChangeDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate")]
        public DateTime MicrosoftVSTSCommonActivatedDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedBy")]
        public MicrosoftVSTSCommonActivatedBy MicrosoftVSTSCommonActivatedBy { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority")]
        public int MicrosoftVSTSCommonPriority { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Microsoft.VSTS.TCM.AutomationStatus")]
        public string MicrosoftVSTSTCMAutomationStatus { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Html
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class Links
    {
        public Avatar avatar { get; set; }
        public Self self { get; set; }
        public WorkItemUpdates workItemUpdates { get; set; }
        public WorkItemRevisions workItemRevisions { get; set; }
        public WorkItemComments workItemComments { get; set; }
        public Html html { get; set; }
        public WorkItemType workItemType { get; set; }
        public Fields fields { get; set; }
    }

    public class MicrosoftVSTSCommonActivatedBy
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string uniqueName { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public string descriptor { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestCaseModel
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int rev { get; set; }
        public Fields fields { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Self
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class SystemAssignedTo
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string uniqueName { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public string descriptor { get; set; }
    }

    public class SystemChangedBy
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string uniqueName { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public string descriptor { get; set; }
    }

    public class SystemCreatedBy
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public Links _links { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string uniqueName { get; set; }
        public string imageUrl { get; set; }
        public string descriptor { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkItemComments
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkItemRevisions
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkItemType
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkItemUpdates
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
    }



   }
```

Comment: Firstly, I didn't see any field that allows to know which `TestSuiteModel.value` is the parent from a `TestCasesModel.` and we would use `TestCaseModel.id` == `TestCasesModel.value[x].TestCase.id` to know if `TestCasesModel.value` is the parent from `TestCaseModel`? You need a way to link them in order to display them correctly. This could be using a ViewModel or a Dictionary that you would be populating when getting the data.

Comment: Secondly, what do you expect from `GetTestSuites`? Seems to me that you are just overwriting `TestCases` and `TestCase` all over again and you will only get the last iteration result of both `foreach`. You need to store those values in a Collection or in a Dictionary as suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: Do you have any blazor code?

Comment: @ConnorLow I can create an new Balzor app and share it but I don't know where.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine I don't understand the question about `value` each model has nested property, but as long as the models are separated by namespaces i don't think there will be an issue. For your second question, yes I am rewriting `TestCase` but I need a property that will store the unique value during the foreach loop. If TestCase is re-written it doesn't matter, as long as there is an array (which the question is about) that just stores them somewhere else

Comment: @elektra The comment was about the fact that you didn't necessarily have a way to determinate a parent object from the child not that you would have any naming issues. Which was some kind of introduction to the second comment. For the second matter, I gave you a hint about a Dictionary or a ViewModel: simple example: `Dictionay<int, List<TestCasesModel>>`, the key being a unique key of `TestSuiteModel.Value`: `id`

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine thanks, maybe I don't understand something but the code I provided works. If I query all three objects, I can see the data stored on the browser without any complaints about the value.  The only thing I asked is just how to create a property bag to store the items like `[ array 1 : [testsuite 1, testcases1, testcase1], 2 : [] ]`

Answer (score 1):

You can try by creating ViewModels, I didn't try this code:

```
public class TestSuiteModelValueVM
{
    public ABC.Models.TestSuiteModel.Value TestSuiteModelValue { get; set; }
    public TestCasesModelVM TestCasesModelVM { get; set; }
}

public class TestCasesModelVM
{
    public TestCasesModel TestCasesModel { get; set; }
    public List<TestCaseModelVM> TestCasesVMList { get; set; }
}

public class TestCaseModelVM
{
    public ABC.Models.TestCasesModel.Value TestCasesModelValue { get; set; }
    public TestCaseModel TestCaseModel { get; set; }
}

public List<TestSuiteModelValueVM> TestSuiteModelValueVMList { get; set; } = new();


public async Task GetTestSuites()
{
    string url = "https://dev.azure.com/****/****/_apis/test/Plans/12/suites?api-version=5.0";
    TestSuiteModel testSuites = await TestSuiteService.GetTestSuites(url);

    if (testSuites != null)
    {
        foreach (var ts in testSuites.value)
        {
            TestCasesModel testCases = await TestCasesService.GetTestCases(ts.testCasesUrl);
            if (testCases?.value != null)
            {
                TestCasesModelVM testCasesModelVM = new TestCasesModelVM
                {
                    TestCasesModel = testCases,
                    TestCasesVMList = new()
                };
                foreach (var tcs in testCases.value)
                {
                    TestCaseModel testCase = await TestCaseService.GetTestCase(tcs.testCase.url);
                    TestCaseModelVM testCaseModelVM = new TestCaseModelVM
                    {
                        TestCasesModelValue = tcs,
                        TestCaseModel = testCase
                    };

                    testCasesModelVM.TestCasesVMList.Add(testCaseModelVM);
                }
                TestSuiteModelValueVM testSuiteModelValueVM = new TestSuiteModelValueVM
                {
                    TestSuiteModelValue = ts,
                    TestCasesModelVM = testCasesModelVM
                };
                TestSuiteModelValueVMList.Add(testSuiteModelValueVM);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using some slightly strange naming conventions and breaking one of my rules:

1. Rule: don't have two objects with the same name in different namespaces - `Value`.  What does `Value` mean?  Give each object a more descriptive name.
2. `TestSuiteModel` isn't a model, it's a collection object.

Anyway, as constructing a working example with your objects would be toooo difficult, I've used one of my Demo data providers to demonstrate my answer in a simpler data setting.

Here's my `DataProvider` implemented as a singleton pattern class.  It provides lists of continents, countries and cities.  It dummies async behaviour to look like a DbContext or API call.

```cs
public class DataProvider
{
    public async ValueTask<IEnumerable<Continent>> GetContinentsAsync()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        return continentList.AsEnumerable();
    }

    public async ValueTask<IEnumerable<Country>> GetCountriesAsync(Guid continentUid)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        return countryList.Where(item => item.ContinentUid == continentUid).AsEnumerable();
    }

    public async ValueTask<IEnumerable<City>> GetCitiesAsync(Guid countryUid)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        return cityList.Where(item => item.CountryUid == countryUid).AsEnumerable();
    }


    private List<Continent> continentList = new();
    private List<Country> countryList = new();
    private List<City> cityList = new();
    
    private DataProvider()
        => this.GetData();

    private static DataProvider? instance;
    public static DataProvider GetInstance()
    {
        instance = instance ?? new DataProvider();
        return instance;
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        var continentUid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var continent = new Continent(continentUid, "Europe");
        continentList.Add(continent);

        var countryUid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var country = new Country(countryUid, continentUid, "UK");
        countryList.Add(country);
        cityList.Add(new(Guid.NewGuid(), countryUid, "London"));
        cityList.Add(new(Guid.NewGuid(), countryUid, "Bristol"));

        countryUid = Guid.NewGuid();
        country = new Country(countryUid, continentUid, "France");
        countryList.Add(country);
        cityList.Add(new(Guid.NewGuid(), countryUid, "Paris"));
        cityList.Add(new(Guid.NewGuid(), countryUid, "Lyon"));

        continentUid = Guid.NewGuid();
        continent = new Continent(continentUid, "Oceania");
        continentList.Add(continent);

        countryUid = Guid.NewGuid();
        country = new Country(countryUid, continentUid, "Australia");
        countryList.Add(country);
        cityList.Add(new(Guid.NewGuid(), countryUid, "Adelaide"));
        cityList.Add(new(Guid.NewGuid(), countryUid, "Perth"));
    }

}

public record Continent(Guid Uid, string Name);
public record Country(Guid Uid, Guid ContinentUid, string Name);
public record City(Guid Uid, Guid CountryUid, string Name);
```

I then define a simple "Bag" object, to capture the item/sub-item structure.

```cs
public class BagCollection<TItem, TBagItem>
{
    public TItem Item { get; private set; }
    public IEnumerable<TBagItem> SubItems => _subItems;

    private List<TBagItem> _subItems;

    public void AddSubItem(TBagItem bag)
    {
        _subItems.Add(bag);
    }

    public BagCollection(TItem parent, List<TBagItem> bag)
    {
        this.Item = parent;
        _subItems = bag;
    }
}
```

Use this to build the item -> subitem structure that is retrieved by the API calls:

```cs
@code {
    private DataProvider _dataProvider = DataProvider.GetInstance();
    private List<BagCollection<Continent, BagCollection<Country, City>>> _continents = new();

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var continents = await _dataProvider.GetContinentsAsync();
        foreach (var continent in continents)
        {
            var continentData = new BagCollection<Continent, BagCollection<Country, City>>(continent, new List<BagCollection<Country, City>>());
            var countries = await _dataProvider.GetCountriesAsync(continent.Uid);
            foreach(var country in countries)
            {
                var cities = await _dataProvider.GetCitiesAsync(country.Uid);
                var countrydata = new BagCollection<Country, City>(country, cities.ToList());
                continentData.AddSubItem(countrydata);
            }
            _continents.Add(continentData);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally iterate through the collections to get out the data.  Sort the sub-items if you wish.

```cs
@foreach (var continent in _continents)
{
    <div class="bg-light m-2 p-1">
        <h2>@continent.Item.Name</h2>
        @foreach (var country in continent.SubItems)
        {
            <div class="m-2 p-1 ps-3">
                <h3>@country.Item.Name</h3>
                @foreach (var city in country.SubItems.OrderBy(items => items.Name))
                {
                    <div class="m-2 p-1 ps-5">
                        @city.Name
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your time, unfortunately your code is too complex to migrate your logic into mine. I am not even sure what most of the code does